# Using variable in building a Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have seen several similar questions on SO, but not exactly what I'm looking for.

I want to use a variable in my regEx so that when I call it, I can easily pass in a number.

Here's the hard coded regEx:

```
'mywonderfullString'.match(/.{1,3}/g)
```

Here's what I need:

```
'mywonderfullString'.match(/.{1,variableHERE}/g)
```

So when I call the regEx, I would do something like

```
'mywonderfullString'.match(/.{1,3}/g)
```

I've seen some examples using the replace regEx, but I can't seem to my example working.

Comment: The only thing `.{1,x}` will do is confirm that the string is *at least* `x` characters long. Why not just `str.length >= x`...!?

Comment: @deceze, it will actually check that it's *no longer than*.

Comment: @ndn That would require `^` and `$` anchors...

Comment: @deceze, you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`RegExp` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) in-order to include variables inside regex.

```js
var variableHERE = '3'
alert('mywonderfullString'.match(new RegExp(".{1," + variableHERE + "}", "g")))
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp